# Requirement.txt file in python

Tags: php, python

I want to install PHP on the server. and I want to install it with Python script. Can I include PHP (some version number) in the reqirements.txt file and install it on the server?
If not, then how can I install PHP on the server using a python script?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install php as a python package. Have a look at [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/), [ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/) or [salt](http://www.saltstack.com/community/)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. Have a look at configuration management tools like [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/), or [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com/community/).